powershell - format output per folder name while comparing two text files
I am trying to compare the permissions of users in a list of folders for source and target server saved in two text files and collect the differences in a third file. I am able to capture the differences between file 1 and 2, however I am unable to format the output to display as per each folder name in file 1 and 2. My current output looks like below:
The current folder is Output}                                                   Target       
User domain\name has 'FullControl' rights in Output}                            Target       

The current folder is Script}                                                   Target       
User domain\name has 'FullControl' rights in Script}                            Target       

The current folder is Output}                                                   Source       
User domain\vname has 'ReadAndExecute, Synchronize' rights in Output}           Source       

The current folder is Script}                                                   Source       
User domain\vname has 'ReadAndExecute, Synchronize' rights in Script}     Source       

Need assistance to format this output as per the folder names as below
The current folder is Output}                                                   Target       
User domain\name has 'FullControl' rights in Output}                            Target 

The current folder is Output}                                                   Source       
User domain\vname has 'ReadAndExecute, Synchronize' rights in Output}           Source

The current folder is Script}                                                   Target       
User domain\name has 'FullControl' rights in Script}                            Target 

The current folder is Script}                                                   Source       
User domain\vname has 'ReadAndExecute, Synchronize' rights in Script}     Source 

The code:
$file1 = Get-Content $outfile1
$file2 = Get-Content $outfile2

$diffcheck = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $file1 -DifferenceObject $file2 | Out-File  $tempfile
             
get-content -Path $tempfile | Select-Object -Skip 4 | Sort-Object  | Out-File $output


Please add a [mcve] of what you currently have created.

$permission | % {Write-Output "User $($.IdentityReference) has '$($.FileSystemRights)' rights in $leaf" | out-file $outfile1 -Append }

Don't write the code you have tried in a comment. Instead, [edit] your post an add it in there as formatted text

The code you have now added to your post just compares the textual contents of the two files. Nothing there about user permissions.. What exacly is in those files? Just lists of folders you need to get the permissions for? Then why is this in two separate files and not just one? Why not get the permissions for these folders and store the results in a structured output file like a CSV ?

The  code actually gets the permission details for all the users in the child folders for the specified parent folder and since it is running in two different paths, it is storing in two text files. This is a part of migration where we are comparing the permissions of the users in the source and migrated folders to ensure the users have similar permissions and if any missing/different then should be shown in the third file.
